How do you get Puppeteer to install the right version of Chrome?
I ran npx puppeteer browsers install chrome, and it responded with chrome@122.0.6261.111 /root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-122.0.6261.111/chrome-linux64/chrome.
Then I ran ts-node with some code that uses puppeteer, and I got this message:
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 127.0.6533.88). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /root/.cache/puppeteer).

So why does npx puppeteer browsers install chrome install version 122.0.6261.111 when puppeteer actually needs version 127.0.6533.88? More importantly, how do I fix this? I tried npm install beforehand to make sure puppeteer was the right version.

chrome@122.0.6261.111 corresponds to puppeteer 22.4.1 and 127.0.6533.88 to either 22.15.0 or 23.0.0 so you are probably invoking different Puppeteer installations. To fix it make sure, that you run npx puppeteer browsers install chrome in the project (where node_modules containing puppeteer are) and your code does not actually have a different version of puppeteer in subfolders/subprojects.

That is great information to know. Sounds like there is a 1:1 correspondence between the puppeteer version and the chrome version. That led me to discover this document, which is very helpful. Thanks!

It's weird because I go 1. cd to the folder with the package.json, 2. npm install, 3. npx puppeteer browsers install chrome, and yet the version in my package.json is ^22.4.1, and the browser install says it installed chrome@122.0.6261.111, so everything looks right. Then it's only when I run the code that it says it wants a newer chrome for some reason...

Each Puppeteer version corresponds to a single Chrome version.
In this case, the underlying code must have been somehow using the wrong Puppeteer version.
To fix the problem, I just ran npm install puppeteer@latest to make sure the version was up to date.
